# DB2: How to move data in BLOB to a CLOB

Tags: database, db2

My solution is:

(1) create a new column, named "MESSAGE_CLOB"

(2) convert the bytes in "MESSAGE" (the existing BLOB column) to a string in the charset which is used when inserting, and then store the string in MESSAGE_CLOB column for all records in the table

(3) delete the existing column "MESSAGE" (BLOL)

(4) rename the column "MESSAGE_CLOB" to "MESSAGE"

My problem is at the step 2, firstly, I want to use DB2 to convert it to string

```
SELECT CAST(MESSAGE as CLOB(1M) CCSID 1047) as MESSAGE_CLOB
FROM SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
WHERE ID = '0264000060'
```

1047 is the CCSID for IBM1047 charset.

And then

```
UPDATE SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
SET MESSAGE_CLOB = (
SELECT CAST(MESSAGE as CLOB(1M) CCSID 1047) as MESSAGE_CLOB
FROM SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
WHERE ID = '0264000060'
)
WHERE ID = '0264000060';
```

But the 1st SQL doesn't work. It reports the below error

```
[2023-11-29 16:15:20] [42601][-104] ILLEGAL SYMBOL "1047". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: ) CCSID FOR. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14
[2023-11-29 16:15:20] [26501][-514] THE CURSOR SQL_CURLH200C1 IS NOT IN A PREPARED STATE. SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, DRIVER=4.26.14
```

Appreciate a lot if you can advise!

---

Update: DB2 doesn't allow convert BLOB data to CLOB.
in [DB2 CAST function document](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=expressions-cast-specification), it says that:

> The supported casts are shown in [Casting between data types](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_castingbetweendatatypes.html). If the cast is not supported, an error is returned.

And in [Casting between data types](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_castingbetweendatatypes.html), we can find that BLOB is not supported to be converted to CLOB.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Key question: What encoding was used to convert the characters to bytes?

Comment: @TheImpaler IBM1047, but we don't care which charset is used by DB2 to store a string in CLOB column.

Comment: Hi @mustaccio update the error when I think as "it doesn't work"